# Moving from Guice to Spring: beans with default constructor and properties handling

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, guice

I just have finished moving my pet project from Guice to Spring DI. I want to share some notes and ask for advice. 
Guice config was done with annotations (the only possible way), and Spring config is also only with annotations: one AppConfig class annotated with @Configuration and a plenty of bean creation methods annotated with @Bean inside.

Observations and questions:

1. Spring's configuration is full of methods that create beans with
   default no-args constructor:

   > ```
   > @Bean
   > public DataProvider getDataProvider() {
   >     return new DataProvider();
   > }
   > ```

   Thats definitely bad. Guice instantiates beans with default
   constructor without any additional configuration. Can I do this in
   Spring? I know that if I add @Component annotation along with
   classpath scanning annotation it will do the trick. But: 1.
   injecting with @Component is different from injecting with @Bean 2.
   I need to scatter my configuration among even more files than while
   just adding @Autowired. Thats bad. The only solution to keep all
   configs in one place is old good XML configuration, but again with
   explicit declaration of all beans.  Or I am wrong and this can be
   done better in Spring?
2. Properties files handling. While working with Guice I did a bad thing: I have scattered @Named annotation along huge number of private fields where property values were injected. Sometimes there were 5 properties to be injected in some class - and this resulted in 5 annotations. That was not a good solution.I tried to do better with Spring, but the only thing I have found is instantiating and injecting Configuration files everywhere. Just take a look of this perfection:

   > ```
   > @Bean
   > public MyProjectStorageConfiguration getStorageConfiguration(
   >         @Value("${mongo.collections.names})") String mongoNames,
   >         @Value("${mongo.collections.data})") String mongoData,
   >         @Value("${files.maindata})") String mainData,
   >         @Value("${files.secondarydata})") String secondaryData,
   >         @Value("${files.backupdata})") String backupData,
   >         @Value("${files.additionaldata})") String additionalData) {
   >     return new MyProjectStorageConfiguration(mongoNames,mongoData, mainData,secondaryData,backupData,additionalData);
   > }
   > ```

Looks like my pet project needs to be refactored again. Any suggestions?

Comment: I am not sure with point 1, but point 2 could be done by writing a bean post-processor that gets the bean after creation. You could then inspect your own bean and auto-inject property types, like for example Strings or integers. Of course you'd need to come up with either a convention on how you name injectable properties, or yet another annotation that marks it as a property. Then, as convention, your field names can correspond to property names and you can resolve them without any annotations on the beans? Personally though I find it nice to make this explicit. Too much magic kills ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes, you're right. This is really a bad habit. 
   But it's not caused by Spring itself, just by the way the tutorials and all the other things are written. In fact you can use `@Autowired` in constructor and Spring will inject the intefaces/classes that fit with the type of the required parameter. 
   With one, big, thing to remember (coming from Guice): if you have two or more instances of the same interface (two different implementations), to select the right one you have no chance then moving out the parameter to a setter adding the annotations `@Autowired` and `@Qualifier("[beanName]")`. Or move everything to a configuration file...

   ```
   @Service
   class AClass implements MyService {

      @Autowired
      public AClass(UniqueInterface uniqueInterface) {
       ...
      }

      @Autowired
      @Qualifier("[beanName]")
      public void setAnInterface(NotUniqueInterface notUniqueInterface) {
         ...
      }
   }
   ```
2. Normally you can inject property value directly in code. See [values injection modes](https://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/spring-framework/spring-from-the-trenches-injecting-property-values-into-configuration-beans/). But, in a way or another, you'll need to inject the values with annotations or using the configuration beans. There's no others ways (at least for what I know...).